# How to change from http to https?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Does anyone can tell me how to change from http to htpps? My domain name have SSL. I used to create file .htaccess in the root, but it is not work at all.

**Here is the code of .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please help, Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For direct access, this seems to be the way to go:

```
RewriteEngine on

# rewrite to HTTPS
RewriteCond ${HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

(based on the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

But if you're behind a proxy (such as a load balancer), you'll need to use the headers it sends. Here's the code I use for this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# rewrite to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

It's served me well, and is fairly self-explanatory.

Of course you could combine both to make it more robust, but that's overkill in any real situation where you know how it will be used;

```
RewriteEngine on

# rewrite to HTTPS
RewriteCond ${HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Accorting to [this site](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/ssl-example-usage-in-htaccess.html) (first result on google)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

should work.